# Meaning/picture of the statement: "Turbulent flow is chaotic. However, not all chaotic flows are turbulent"

Tags: turbulence, chaos-theory

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) states that

> *Turbulent flow is chaotic. However, not all chaotic flows are turbulent.*

Someone give a picture for that?

Comment: You want a picture that shows that not all chaotic flows are turbulent?

Comment: A picture or explanation whatever you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's largely a matter of definition.  Here are some quotes.

From Springer Reference:

> Definition There is no universally recognized definition of chaotic
>   flows. Flows with properties that are neither constant in time nor
>   presenting any regular periodicity are normally referred as chaotic.
>   Fluid turbulence is generally found to be chaotic. It is also random,
>   dissipative, and multiple scaled in time and space. It is a complex
>   system of infinite degrees of freedom.

A paper full of state diagrams (but rather heavy on the math) for transitions to chaotic flow:  https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/25484/1/Transition%20to%20chaos%20in%20converging-diverging%20channel%20flows.pdf

And finally, a nice discussion at quora.com  (registration apparently required)

> As Piyush Grover pointed out, a chaotic flow has to have mixing by
>   definition. The  following answer assumes 'chaotic' to mean 'random'
>   which is technically  incorrect. But I've decided to leave it here
>   anyway, because I  think that's what the OP meant. However, I still
>   think that you won't observe a k^(-5/3) spectrum in the case of
>   chaotic advection.
>
> I'm also adding Piyush's comment as a part of this answer.
>
> Chaotic  but non-turbulent flows can have exponential mixing. There is
>   a whole  field of chaotic advection based on this fact. In fact, you
>   can have  exponential mixing of mass in Stokes flow, which is as far
>   away from  turbulence as possible. This is often used to mix fluid
>   efficiently at  micro devices (low Re), where turbulence is simply not
>   feasible due to  energy considerations.
>
> A  chaotic flow is one in which there seems to be a high irregularity
>   in the behavior of one/all flow variables with time/space. While a
>   turbulent flow certainly exhibits this behavior, there are also other
>   properties that should be present for a flow to be called turbulent,
>   one of which is high levels of mixing, i.e., mass/momentum/heat
>   transfer.
>
> This is a distinct (and perhaps the most useful) property of turbulent
>   flows which is frequently exploited. When you try to mix the sugar in
>   a cup of coffee by stirring it, you're essentially making use of this
>   property. This effect can be clearly seen by looking at the velocity
>   profiles of laminar and turbulent flows through a pipe.
>
> [image]
>
> (Taken from Page on Flowcontrolnetwork)
>
> The lines show the magnitude of horizontal/streamwise velocities with
>   respect to height along a pipe. You can see that the turbulent flow
>   has a much flatter velocity profile than a laminar flow, i.e., there
>   are higher velocities close to the wall for a turbulent flow compared
>   to a laminar flow, while there are lower velocities close to the
>   centerline for a turbulent flow compared to a laminar flow. This shows
>   that velocity (momentum for an incompressible/constant density flow)
>   is transferred to a greater extent from the fluid elements close to
>   the centerline to the fluid elements close to the walls in case of a
>   turbulent flow.
>
> A good example of a flow which is chaotic but is not turbulent is the
>   trail behind an aircraft. Though the flow inside the jet trail is
>   highly chaotic, it is not turbulent because it maintains the shape
>   (diameter) for very large distances behind the aircraft, which means
>   that there is very low/negligible mixing with the surrounding
>   atmosphere.