# Are all turbulent flows chaotic?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics, chaos-theory, turbulence

I have often read that [all turbulent flows are chaotic](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_clear_separation_between_chaos_and_turbulence). I have come across [a few explanations on web forums](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106529/meaning-picture-of-the-statement-turbulent-flow-is-chaotic-however-not-all-c), but are there any authoritative references/textbooks that explicitly cover this question?

Comment: I think so but that does not mean all systems have no deterministic solutions...

Answer (score 1):

To answer this you have to study the theory of turbulence from the point of view of dynamical systems. The first to propose that there is such thing as a 'turbulent attractor' were Ruelle and Takens in their famous paper 'On the Nature of Turbulence'. Some books on this matter are 'Dynamical Systems Approach to Turbulence' (Jensen, Paladin and Vulpiani) and ChaosBook (Predrag Cvitanovic, you can access for free to this [here](https://chaosbook.org/)). If you're asking 'Is there a critical Reynolds number?', in the case of pipes flows, a critical Reynolds number of $Re_c=2040 \pm 10$ has been proposed by studying the mean lifetime of turbulent puffs ('The Onset of Turbulence in Pipe Flow', Avila et al., 2011. This transition scenario is different from the one proposed by Ruelle and Takens).